# Xamarin -- support for 9-patch?

Tags: android, ios, windows-store-apps, xamarin, nine-patch

Does Xamarin support 9-patch images in a cross-platform way?  The ideal would be to create the image from the same file for iOS, Android, and Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best I can tell, the answer appears to be "not in any way that makes sense for me to use."  The best option is going to be to have separate image resources for each platform.  The [splat library](https://github.com/paulcbetts/splat) does do some cross-platform image handling, but not 9-patch, and I'm not sure about its performance.

Comment: I would say this is "by design". The philosophy of Xamarin is to provide native UI components for a native look-and-feel, so this would only be possible if iOS and Windows also supported 9-patch images.

Comment: IOS and Windows both do support 9-patch images.